# How to dymamically set background color of AngularJS ngTable table row

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have an angularjs app using several dynamic ngTables.  As a result of a search operation executed on the page, I need to "highlight" one of the rows in one of the tables, but I'd like to remove the highlight after the user takes some action (any CTA execution, I would suppose).

I've managed to figure out how to add the "bold" class (although I really need to change the background color) to my "tr", "td", or a "span" around the content of a "td", using the data ngTable is iterating over.  I've verified this in Firebug.  However, I see no change on the screen.  I'm guessing that the CSS settings used in ngTable are overriding what I'm setting.

What do I have to do to make ngTable change the background color of the table row?

Once I figure this out, I'll probably remove the class setting on a "$timeout" or on some CTA action.

Answer (score 2):

**ng-class**
 can be used to specify class. And It is possible to write expressions for ng-class.
For eg:

```
<table ng-repeat="questions in comment.employee">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-class="{{e.ID == 1 ? 'class1' : 'class2'}} " >
            <td>
                 {{e.Name}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok, I should have elaborated.  I know all of this.  I'm using ng-class to set the "bold" class.  The problem is, it just doesn't do anything.  I inspected the element in Firebug, and the element does have that class, but nothing changes on the screen.  As I said, I think the CSS for ngTable is preventing ordinary CSS changes on table rows in the ngTable, I just don't quite understand that.

Comment: That should not happen normally. Check the css priority.

Comment: I was able to view those examples a few days ago, but today it fails every time with DNS or miscellaneous errors.  I've tried it on three different devices on three different networks.

Comment: Hmm. Got it now.  Inspecting.

Comment: Another goose egg.  I even tried the very class from the example, and I put it in quotes (I hadn't before).  No difference.  I still see the class in Firebug, but no change on the screen.  I see the change in the example (when I don't get DNS or timeout errors), but not in my app.

Comment: Ah, got it.  I thought "emphasis" was from bootstrap.  I needed to define that class in my own app's css.